# Is possible to represent natural number X without 'splitting' it as additive-finitely repeated element set property?

Tags: natural-numbers, multisets

I have a $Set$ of elements $n$ (a multiset).
Each element of this set $n$ is the same, is a multiset because one element $n$ is replicable using addition operation, in other words we can have finitely repeated element set
My problem is just that: I don't want a finitely *repeated* element $Set$ but just return to a single element $n$ without this being repeatable

> The natural numbers are "closed" under addition and multiplication. A $Set$ is closed (under an operation) if and only if the operation on any two elements of the set produces another element of the same set.

My goal is to find a way to represent a particular natural number X without use the addition because my goal is to avoid to reach this natural number $X$ 'splitting' it into many parts (I don't want a subset as a sum $n+n+n+n+n$..)
But problem is that each element of this $Set$ is a *natural* number

I perform a sum $n+n+n+n$... until I reach final natural $X$

We have a natural number **of addition operations** not a 'a natural number' of elements because in my situation $Set$ is a natural number of operations not of elements (that are'numbers')

$X$ = addition$+$addition$+$addition$+$addition...

is not an *addition* of elements but an *addition of addition*

$X = n+n+n+n...$

but my problem is this: can we use another category where $n+n+n$.. does not return me a addition of addition but a single element without to form a finitely repeated element set but only 'the element' ?